# sql server Get the FULL month name from a date

Tags: sql, sql-server, date-conversion

How do I use sql to get the whole month name in sql server?
I did't find a way using `DATEPART(mm, mydate)` or `CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), CreatedFor, 107)`.

Basically I need in the format: *April 1 2009*.

Comment: if you can filter through php it's not too hard...

Comment: [Please read this re: shorthand like `MM`](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2011/09/20/bad-habits-to-kick-using-shorthand-with-date-time-operations.aspx).

Comment: THank you joe, but i am not using php right now. Also i thought its better if the sql query itself can generate the date. I am sure from the server side code after the sql is generated it is easy.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

```
SELECT DATENAME(MONTH, GETDATE()) 
         + RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), GETDATE(), 107), 9) AS [Month DD, YYYY]
```

OR Date without Comma Between date and year,  you can use the following

```
SELECT DATENAME(MONTH, GETDATE()) + ' ' + CAST(DAY(GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR(2))
           + ' ' + CAST(YEAR(GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR(4)) AS [Month DD YYYY]
```

Comment: Please stop recommending date/time shorthand. If you mean `MONTH`, type `MONTH`. [Using shorthand all the time leads to problems](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2011/09/20/bad-habits-to-kick-using-shorthand-with-date-time-operations.aspx).

Comment: How do you know I didn't already up-vote? I visit lots of questions multiple times, and don't always get to everything in one shot - especially when I'm traveling. I suggest not asking people for up-votes. If you write good content it speaks for itself.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Take it easy pal, you dont have to have a go at me it was only a joke. How do I know you didnt upvote for it ? Clearly you didnt agree with what I did (using shorthand), Would you vote for something that you dont agree with ???

Comment: It was a recommendation to not promote the use of lazy shorthand. That doesn't make the answer wrong or not useful, it's just a suggestion to make the answer better.

Answer (score 21):

If you are using SQL Server 2012 or later, you can use:

```
SELECT FORMAT(MyDate, 'MMMM dd yyyy')
```

You can [view the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/hh213505(v=sql.110).aspx) for more information on the format.

Comment: this function is only compatible with sql server 2012. I however have an older version

Comment: The format string needs to be 'MMMM dd yyyy' else you get something like 'January DD YYYY'

Answer (score 3):

Most answers are a bit more complicated than necessary, or don't provide the exact format requested.

```
select Format(getdate(), 'MMMM dd yyyy') --returns 'October 01 2020', note the leading zero
select Format(getdate(), 'MMMM d yyyy') --returns the desired format with out the leading zero: 'October 1 2020'
```

If you want a comma, as you normally would, use:

```
select Format(getdate(), 'MMMM d, yyyy') --returns 'October 1, 2020'
```

Note: even though there is only one 'd' for the day, it will become a 2 digit day when needed.

Answer (score 1):

109  -  mon dd yyyy (In SQL conversion)

The required format is  **April 1 2009**

so

```
 SELECT DATENAME(MONTH, GETDATE()) + RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), GETDATE(), 109), 9)
```

**Result is:**

[image: img1]

Answer (score 0):

```
select datename(DAY,GETDATE()) +'-'+ datename(MONTH,GETDATE()) +'- '+ 
       datename(YEAR,GETDATE()) as 'yourcolumnname'
```

Comment: upto sql server 2008