# convert datetime to display full month

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, datetime, type-conversion

I have searched and i cannot seem to find the answer.  I have tried using different styles, but none of them give me exactly what i want.

I am trying to convert a datetime, that I have calculated.  However I need it to display the full month.

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(25),DATEADD(dd, @codelife, getdate()),107)
```

the above line works fine, EXCEPT it displays the date like

```
Feb 27, 2014
```

I need it to display date like

```
February 27, 2014 etc.....
```

any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nathan's answer seems solid, however if you're using SQL Server 2012 you can make use of the `FORMAT()` function:

```
SELECT FORMAT(GETDATE(),'MMMM dd, yyyy')
```

Or in your case:

```
SELECT FORMAT(DATEADD(dd, @codelife, getdate()),'MMMM dd, yyyy')
```

Comment: wow this format function looks cool cant wait to get my hands on sql 2012 :)

Answer (score 0):

I always use http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/date-formats.aspx as my reference

```
SELECT DATENAME(MM, GETDATE()) + RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), GETDATE(), 107), 9) AS [Month DD, YYYY]
```

I would declare your date as a variable and do something like:

```
DECLARE @myDate DATETIME

SET @myDate = DateAdd(dd, @codelife, getdate());

SELECT DATENAME(MM, @myDate) + RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), @myDate, 107), 9) AS [Month DD, YYYY]
```

Answer (score 0):

You may have to do it in 2 steps.

```
DECLARE @codelife INT = 120

DECLARE @codedate DATETIME = (SELECT (DATEADD(D, @codelife, GETDATE())))

SELECT DATENAME(MM, @codedate) + SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR(25), @codedate, 107), 4, 25)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DATENAME(MONTH, GETDATE()) 
         + RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), GETDATE(), 107), 9) AS [Month DD, YYYY]
```

OR Date without Comma Between date and year, you can use the following

```
SELECT DATENAME(MONTH, GETDATE()) + ' ' + CAST(DAY(GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR(2))
           + ' ' + CAST(YEAR(GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR(4)) AS [Month DD YYYY]
```

I answered the same question a couple of days ago have a look here [sql server Get the FULL month name from a date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19619072/sql-server-get-the-full-month-name-from-a-date/19619119#19619119)