# How to display/select SQL Server datetime column 2015-01-23 to text style January 23, 2015?

Tags: sql-server, datetime

How do I display/select SQL Server `Datetime` column 2015-01-23 to text style January 23, 2015? I'm using SQL Server 9. The basic syntax I'm using in my query is:

```
SELECT LastContactDate, LastProfileReceivedDate
FROM Location
WHERE (Account_Id = '499')
```

I've tried using `CAST (datetime, lastcontactdate, 107) as Date` and using the `Convert` function. most efforts have returned the same style.

My results will show as `2015-01-11 08:48:11.677`    and `2015-01-10 16:17:48.000` but I need to show simply as `January 11, 2015` and `January 10, 2015`. Thanks in advance for any help on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar(12), LastContactDate, 107)
```

Sample output:

> Jan 11, 2015

Source: [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)

If you NEED the full month name, you're going to be stuck with a much nastier query:

```
SELECT DATENAME(MONTH, LastContactDate) 
         + RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), LastContactDate, 107), 9)
```

Sample output:

> January 11, 2015

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19619119/74757

I suppose I better ask the question: why aren't you doing your date formatting in the UI?

Comment: That worked Cory! Thanks. I am using MS SQL SRV Mgt Studio 11 and I am writing the queries manually. Not sure how to effectively use the UI yet, but understand it's better to learn manually first....after using style 107 I decided to use style 101 instead. I have the MS SQL SVR 2008 Fundamentals book, but got confused on how to use the Convert function. Working great now.